# Entity Framework Migrations to multiple Databases

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I have multiple Azure WebServices and their databases. I executed a migration to a test database first. Now, I want to execute the migrations to all databases, but any of those databases have not either Enable-Migrations. How can I execute the migrations to all them?

Comment: I think you need to manually run dotnet ef migrations add --context YourDBContext   for each db you want

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved the problem publishing with enabled execute code first migrations!

Comment: then please mark my answer so anyone can find solutions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually run

```
dotnet ef migrations add --context YourDBContext
```

for each db you want